# QueryDSL DateTime field formatted projection

Tags: java, sql-server, querydsl

I trying to do a query that returns the date and time part of a Datetime field using QueryDSL.

The query in plain SQL looks like this:

```
select convert(varchar, FELectura, 103) as sDate,
       convert(varchar, FELectura, 108) as sTime
from dbo.T2_LecturaEstacionClima;
```

Where FELectura is a DateTime field and the Database is SQL Server 2012.

This query gives the following output:

```
sDate                          sTime                          
------------------------------ ------------------------------ 
02/01/2012                     00:00:00                       
02/01/2012                     01:00:00                       
02/01/2012                     02:00:00                       
02/01/2012                     03:00:00                       
02/01/2012                     08:00:00                       
02/01/2012                     09:00:00                       
02/01/2012                     10:00:00
```

How can i achieve this same output using QueryDSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Querydsl SQL this should work

```
Expression<String> dateExpr = Expressions.stringTemplate("convert(varchar, {0}, 103)", table.feLecutra);
Expression<String> timeExpr = Expressions.stringTemplate("convert(varchar, {0}, 108)", table.feLectura);
List<Tuple> results = query.from(table).list(dateExpr, timeExpr);
```

And to access the columns from a Tuple instance

```
String date = tuple.get(dateExpr);
String time = tuple.get(timeExpr);
```

Comment: How to set alias on the string expression ? Calling .as() on table.feLecutra doesn't translate into correct sql querry